# Execute a dynamic SQL Query against MS Access 2003

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is a *super basic* question but I'm trying to execute a Query that I'm building via some form values against the MS Access database the form resides in.  I don't think I need to go through ADO formally, but maybe I do.

Anyway, some help would be appreciated.  Sorry for being a n00b. ;)

Comment: Can you specify whether you are modifying the data in the database or reading it out for display? I need to know before I vote one of the answers up :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following DAO code to query an Access DB:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE ClassID = " & ClassID)

do while not rs.EOF
  'do stuff
  rs.movenext
loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

In my case, ClassID is a textbox on the form.

Comment: I'd accept this answer except that the If block doesn't function as excepted (I don't think).  It should be `If Not rs.EOF Then`?

Comment: I've edited it to include the "not rs.EOF" and the rs.movenext.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coming up with that actually works.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL Statement)

While Not rs.EOF
    'do stuff
Wend

rs.Close
```

Comment: You need to rs.Movenext statement if you want to iterate through the records in the recordset, assuming SQL will return multiple rows.

Comment: Save yourself a set and use CurrentDb.OpenRecordset().  There is no need to make the separate database object.

Comment: I think that sample code should use best practices, and CurrentDB.OpenRecordset() in DAO can possible leave an explicit object reference hanging. Secondly, as sample code, that's the place where you'd open a *different* database than the current one, so as sample code, I think it's better.

Answer (score 0):

The answers you've been given and that you seem to be accepting loop through a DAO recordset. That is generally a very inefficient method of accomplishing a text. For instance, this:

```
  Set db = CurrentDB()
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("[sql]")
  If rs.RecordCount > 0
     rs.MoveFirst
     Do While Not rs.EOF
       rs.Edit
       rs!Field = "New Data"
       rs.Update
       rs.MoveNext
     Loop 
  End If
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
```

will be much less efficient than:

```
  UPDATE MyTable SET Field = "New Data"
```

which can be run with:

```
  CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE MyTable SET Field = 'New Data'"
```

It is very seldom the case that one needs to loop through a recordset, and in most cases a SQL update is going to be orders of magnitude faster (as well as causing much shorter read/write locks to be held on the data pages).

Comment: Well, question doesn't actually state that an update is being performed. Might be reading data out for display?

Comment: Display in what? A form? If so, then that's not the best way to do it. If in a report, it's *really* not the best way to do it. To me "execute a query" means "update data via a query," but perhaps I'm reading the OP wrong.

Comment: Actually, they said "execute a Query": big Q = big difference. A query (small q) is a SQL DML SELECT, which would prehap imply a recordset. A Query (big Q) is a MS Access (not Jet, not ACE) object that may contain any SQL statement: SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE SQL DML, even SQL DDL or SQL DCL.

Answer (score 0):

Here just in case you wanted an ADO version:

```
Dim cn as new ADODB.Connection, rs as new ADODB.RecordSet
Dim sql as String

set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
sql = "my dynamic sql string"

rs.Open sql, cn ', Other options for the type of recordset to open, adoOpenStatic, etc.

While Not rs.EOF
  'do things with recordset
  rs.MoveNext   ' Can't tell you how many times I have forgotten the MoveNext. silly.
Wend
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

DAO and ADO are very close in usage.  You get more control with DAO and slightly better performance with ADO.  In most access database applications I have come across it really doesn't make a difference.  When I have seen a big difference is with linked tables.  ADO often performs better.

Comment: I've found DAO works faster with Access 97 format databases, and ADO with Access 2000 and greater. I think it's a difference between jet 3.5 and jet 4.0