# SQL - SELECT DISTINCT with field transposition

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation, distinct, transpose

I have a table like this:

```
    cod_amb | field_a | field_b | field_c | field_d | field_e

    21      | N.A.    | Fixed   | N.A.    | N.A.    | Natural   
    21      | Conif   | Temp    | N.A.    | >5 years| Artificial
    21      | N.A.    | Fixed   | N.A.    | N.A.    | Natural   
    24      | N.A.    | Fixed   | N.A.    | N.A.    | Natural   
    24      | NR      | Fixed   | N.A.    | <5 years| Natural   
    24      | N.A.    | Temp    | N.A.    | N.A.    | Natural   
    21      | N.A.    | Fixed   | N.A.    | N.A.    | Natural
```

I have to get a resulting table like this:

```
    cod_amb | param   | value               |

    21      | field_a | N.A., Conif         |
    21      | field_b | Fixed, Temp         |
    21      | field_c | N.A.                |
    21      | field_d | N.A., >5 years      |
    21      | field_e | Natural, Artificial |  
    24      | field_a | N.A., NR            |
    24      | field_b | Fixed, Temp         |
    24      | field_c | N.A.                |
    24      | field_d | N.A., <5 years      |
    24      | field_e | Natural             |
```

Please, can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.
SQL for Access 2007

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
**UPDATE**

I wrote this routine in Access:

```
Sub printSQL()
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim tab As String
tab = "tab_011"
Dim rs1 As dao.Recordset
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(tab)
Dim sqlAll As String
Dim str() As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
ReDim str(i)
Dim fld As dao.Field
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
    If fld.Name = "Area" Then
    ElseIf fld.Name = "lungh" Then
    ElseIf fld.Name = "id_elem" Then
    ElseIf fld.Name = "id_tass" Then
    ElseIf fld.Name = "x_coord" Then
    ElseIf fld.Name = "y_coord" Then
    Else
        str(i) = "SELECT cod_amb, '" & fld.Name & "' AS Param, " & fld.Name & " AS Val "
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve str(i)
    End If
Next
Set fld = Nothing
i = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(str) - 1
    If i = 0 Then
        sqlAll = str(i) & "FROM " & tab & " UNION "
    ElseIf i > 0 And i < UBound(str) - 1 Then
        sqlAll = sqlAll & str(i) & "FROM " & tab & " UNION "
    ElseIf i = UBound(str) - 1 Then
        sqlAll = sqlAll & str(i) & "FROM " & tab & ";"
    End If
Next
Debug.Print sqlAll
End Sub
```

The output of the routine is a string like this:

```
SELECT tab_011.cod_amb, "type_veg" AS Param, type_veg AS Val
FROM tab_011
UNION
SELECT tab_011.cod_amb, "type_acq" AS Param, type_acq AS Val
FROM tab_011
UNION
SELECT tab_011.cod_amb, "status" AS Param, status AS Val
FROM tab_011
UNION
SELECT tab_011.cod_amb, "num_pnt" AS Param, num_pnt AS Val
FROM tab_011
UNION
SELECT tab_011.cod_amb, "terr" AS Param, terr AS Val
FROM tab_011;
```

Finally I run this string in Access as a Union Query and then I export the resulting table in Excel.
The resulting table is slightly different compared with the output shown above: the difference is that column Val contains single occurrence and not the concatenated string.

Comment: What SQL query have your written and tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use code, something like this will work for you:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim sql As String
Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblTable")

sql = ""
Dim fld As DAO.Field
For Each fld In rs.Fields
    If fld.Name <> "cod_amb" Then sql = sql + "SELECT cod_amb, '" + fld.Name + "' AS fldName, " + fld.Name + " AS fldValue FROM tblTable UNION "
Next
Set fld = Nothing

sql = Left(sql, Len(sql) - 6)

MsgBox (sql)

Form_tblTable.RecordSource = sql

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i've already made a macro in Access using a routine similar to yours to print the complete sql string to (copy and paste) run in a query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if you can use PIVOT/UNPIVOT in access 2007 if not you can use a UNION query ...the DECLARE table and insert are just there to make the example work standalone, you would use your own tables.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    cod_amb int,
    field_a varchar(10),
    field_b varchar(10),
    field_c varchar(10),
    field_d varchar(10),
    field_e varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural')
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'Conif','Temp','N.A.','>5 years','Artificial');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (24,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (24,'NR','Fixed','N.A.','<5 years','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (24,'N.A.','Temp','N.A.','N.A.','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural')

SELECT cod_amb, 'field_a' Field, field_a value FROM @table 
UNION
SELECT cod_amb, 'field_b' Field, field_b value FROM @table 
UNION
SELECT cod_amb, 'field_c' Field, field_c value FROM @table 
UNION
SELECT cod_amb, 'field_d' Field, field_d value FROM @table 
UNION
SELECT cod_amb, 'field_e' Field, field_e value FROM @table
```

If you have SQL Server available(or for other SQL server readers who land here), you would use UNPIVOT...again, the DECLARE table and insert are just there to make the example work standalone, you would use your own tables.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
cod_amb int,
field_a varchar(10),
field_b varchar(10),
field_c varchar(10),
field_d varchar(10),
field_e varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural')
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'Conif','Temp','N.A.','>5 years','Artificial');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (24,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (24,'NR','Fixed','N.A.','<5 years','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (24,'N.A.','Temp','N.A.','N.A.','Natural');
INSERT INTO @table(cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
VALUES (21,'N.A.','Fixed','N.A.','N.A.','Natural')


SELECT cod_amb, Field, Value
FROM 
   ( SELECT cod_amb,field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e FROM @table
   ) SourceTable
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR Field IN 
      (field_a,field_b,field_c,field_d,field_e)
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: '@Mack - thanks! I can't use UNPIVOT in Access 2007. But the query works well using UNION SELECT... the problem is that I've to write by hand the whole query structure and the fields in my table are many. I was looking for a method to extract automatically the names of the fields and put distinct value occurrence for each field in a concatenated string.

Comment: If you are willing to use code, this [stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343922/ms-access-2010-get-column-names) shows you how to get the field names out of the system.  Combine this with the union logic above and execute it as a dynamically built query [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133922/how-do-you-execute-a-dynamic-sql-query-against-ms-access-2003-via-vba) from code and you should have a solution to your problem.